# What a way preferred to serve AngularJS partials?

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I am creating an application in AngularJS and Symfony2 with authorization. I don't know how to send html templates from server. There are two methods:

1. Send html templates directly from public directory without a php framework. This is faster and then all frontend application will be in one place. But all application might be downloaded by any man without authorization. This is dangerous.
2. Send html templates via Symfony. Thus I will control template downloading, but for each template I must to create its own route, and all partials will be apart from other application files.

What is you method to serve partials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing them directly would be typical. If this is dangerous, there is a problem with your files. There should never be anything that requires authorization in a template file. If someone accesses them directly, they should simply see useless html and not any sensitive content!!

If you do have private date in those files, remove that data and have that served through the secured api so that your partials can safely be accessed directly.

Comment: From such useless html I may to know about data structure, field names, business logic. The more information there is an attacker, the easier it hack the system.

Comment: @DmitrySkryabin There shouldn't be anything that revealing about business logic in an html file. If you don't believe me, then please propose a circumstance where this could actually happen. If it were an issue, the Angular js devs would have mentioned it. Secure your server-side logic and follow Angular's recommendations: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#description_security-considerations

Comment: Example: I have a template html with header "Customer". From that I know all fields of customers and his format, link to photo directory (or to script who provide a photo). This template also has a button "Create order", and from "new order" template I may to know about courier scheduler types, order closing causes, catalog items structure and so on. All this information in whole may be analyzed by someone in order to identify the bottleneck. Maybe I am mistaken, so please correct me. May be I am just a paranoid :)

Comment: And how does any of that actually help you attack anything? Trust me, it's nothing to worry about. If filtering html files through a secured api were a recommended practice, you would find it in OWASP's recommendations to these attacks: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack. It isn't recommended anywhere, so don't worry about it. They know what they're doing!

Comment: @DmitrySkryabin by following that logic, you shouldn't show any data on your website. Showing any will tell the potential attacker what you  have stored on your website :) Enough sarcasm, yes, you are being paranoid :)

Comment: Okay, you're right :) But for public projects. In private projects (such as CRM) the best way is to protect all files, even templates. It is my humble opinion.

Comment: @DmitrySkryabin It doesn't seem like you're going to accept an answer here unless someone says that you're right :(

Comment: I agree with your arguments, and I chose the direct way to return statics. In my schema, client receives a main application page only after login, and thus, an unauthorized user can not find links to templates and scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the discussion of security aside, I simply use a partials controller and give it the name of the html file I want.  The single route looks like:

```
cerad_ang_partials:
    pattern:  /partials/{partial}
    defaults: 
        _controller: cerad_ang.partials.controller:getAction
```

I then have a Resources/partials directory for storing the partials.  I don't use twig for partial files.  Mixing twig and angularjs notation was too confusing for me.

Comment: I do the same thing in python tornado. Using (r"/partials/(.*\.html)", PartialHandler). In Partial handler use self.render("path" + filename)

Comment: why would you want to execute Symfony for simple partials?

Comment: Most of the time I don't.  But note the part of the question concerning security.  If for some reason I need to restrict access then going through Symfony makes more sense.